# selenium-chromedriver: Is it possible to access everything in the browser Inspector-Network page?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

In Chrome, in F12-Network there are lots of network requests, for example for stackoverflow homepage there are:

```
- stackoverflow.com
- jquery.min.js
- stub.en.js?v=xxxxxxxxx
- stacks.css?v=xxxxxxxxx
- ...
```

Is it possible to get these requests?

Comment: Seems not for Python so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from question, but I guess you were to access all these requests via Selenium API. Yes, it became possible with Selenium 4.

Sample below shows catching requests on the google page

```java
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // driver should be of type ChromeDriver
DevTools chromeDevTools = driver.getDevTools();
chromeDevTools.createSession();

chromeDevTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
chromeDevTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(),
        req -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Sent %s request to %s",
                    req.getRequest().getMethod(),
                    req.getRequest().getUrl()
            ));
        });
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

chromeDevTools.send(Network.disable());
driver.close();
```